# Конструкция с союзом "как" (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

***Она вырядилась как новогодняя елка.***
Здесь же запятая ставиться не будет, верно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По смыслу здесь *сравнительный оборот* (хотя в редком контексте и возможно, что она намеренно изображала из себя ёлку), поэтому запятая **нужна**. Похожий пример из учебника:

> Нет, ну вы посмотрите на него, вырядился, как клоун.
>
> *Практическая
> грамматика русского языка для всех, А. Горбатова, 2015*

Не нужна запятая в случаях со значением "нарядиться кем-то" (к маскараду он вырядился как священник), поскольку тогда оборот входит в состав сказуемого и без него предложение не имеет законченного смысла.

http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

Comment: Можно Вам еще вопрос?

Comment: Давайте - как говорят в Восточной Африке, kuuliza si ujinga :).

Comment: Ну, например: "Он танцует как Майкал Джексон". Здесь же запятой не будет?

Comment: Танцует "так же хорошо" или подражает Майклу Джексону (танцует в его стиле)?

Comment: Запятая ставится? (Да) Я просто во всем этом путаюсь как не знаю кто, честно.

Comment: В большинстве контекстов (кроме конкретного разговора о стиле) это будет сравнительный оборот (напр. со стороны кому-то напомнил Майкла Джексона), запятая нужна.

Comment: Можем ли мы продолжить разговор в чате? У меня к Вам много вопросов. (Простите, что настолько тупа)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80697/discussion-between--and-alex-ander).

Comment: Давайте, только не наговаривайте на себя :)

Answer (score 1):

**вырядиться**
-ряжусь, -рядишься; *св.; разг.*
Одеться излишне нарядно, экстравагантно или несообразно погоде, обстоятельствам и т. п.
*Вырядились как на праздник.*

Предложение без оборота воспринимается вполне логично: она вырядилась.
Все понимают, что девушка (или женщина) оделась как-то по-особенному.
А вот **как именно**? На кого или на что стала похожа? На эти вопросы отвечает **сравнительный оборот** — как новогодняя елка.
Я бы поставила запятую, если, конечно, смысл предложения именно такой.

С запятой (как кто?):
*Но потом был новогодний вечер — и я вырядилась, как дура, во все лучшее...*
Ю. Поляков. Убегающий от любви

Без запятой (в качестве кого):
*Ее (…) вырядили как лихую куртизанку — короткая юбка, высоченные каблуки, вызывающее декольте, броский макияж.*
М. Лазарева. Фрейлина королевской безопасности

[Запятая перед "как"](http://litmasters.ru/minutka-gramotnosti/zapyataya-pered-soyuzom-kak.html)

Comment: А если, например, такое предложение: "Дмитрий посмотрел на девушку как на дикарку". Тут же тоже, по сути, должна быть запятая.

Comment: Контекста нет, но думаю, что запятая нужна.  Вот что-то похожее: _Он посмотрел на меня, как на пустое место, молча подал мне руку._  В. Ф. Джунковский, Воспоминания (1915–1917)

Comment: А если (по контексту) Дмитрий буквально не смотрел на девушку, а напр. прочитал присланное резюме, что-то ему показалось, условно говоря, "диким" (он _воспринял_ её как дикарку), и он отказал ей в приёме на работу?

Answer (score 1):

**Обособление зависит от смысла.**

Мне не нравится, как она оделась. **Вырядилась как новогодняя елка, вкуса никакого**. Оборот уточняет семантику глагола: оделась ярко, во  всё разноцветное, нет единого стиля.

Почему она сегодня такая нарядная? **Вырядилась, как новогодняя ёлка**.  Здесь основное значение глагола: оделась очень празднично.

**Пояснение**

1) **Вырядиться** ― (разг). одеться излишне нарядно, экстравагантно или несообразно погоде, обстоятельствам и т.п. Обычно так выражается неодобрение или проявляется интерес: зачем так нарядно оделась?

2) **Можно просто вырядиться,** и смысл будет понятен из семантики глагола без дополнительного распространения:  И чего ты сегодня так вырядилась? Ну вот, и эта вырядилась! Не взяли тебя, — сказала она злорадно. — Ишь, вырядилась!.. [Ю. М. Нагибин. (1972-1979)]

3) Но очень часто этот глагол имеет **зависимые слова, уточняющие ситуацию.** Итак, вырядиться можно как? во что? зачем/куда? для кого?

Вырядилась **барыней**.  Вырядилась в слишком яркий для ее возраста пиджак; вырядилась в элегантный костюм, одолженный у подруги. Она, наверное, **на свидание** вырядилась. Ты что! **Куда вырядилась?**

4) Сравнительный оборот  обособляется, если отвечает **на вопросы зачем/куда? для кого?**

Вырядилась, как на вечерний прием/как на свидание/как на свадьбу.

5) **Вырядилась, как дура** (зачем-то вырядилась). Оборот оценивает поступок, но не распространяет глагол.

6) **Вырядился, как клоун.**  Оделся экстравагантно, как клоун. Идет повтор значения, поэтому оборот обособляется. Здесь броская одежда не оценивается как негативная. Возможно, она просто не подходит к ситуации или не соответствует  скромному имиджу остальных.

Он всегда вырядится как клоун (= в яркое и безвкусное).

Вывод

**Оборот не обособляется, если он содержит дополнительные детали, раскрывающие семантику глагола "вырядиться".** Иногда это не так легко определить, поэтому желательно иметь контекст и понимать ситуацию.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я хоть как-то начала в это "врубаться", скажем так. Но я не думаю, что на долго покину всех вас со своей любимой и в то же время проблематичной темой.